# Conditional Where clause in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

```
select colA, colB from car
where car.id in (select id from make) and 
car.id in (select id from model);
```

The above query works perfectly file as is, say there is a case that the make table has not been popluated with anything. just an empty table. is there a way to make the join not take place on that table?

Basically, if the table has 1 or more rows, apply the where condition. Otherwise, ignore and dont limit it.

Is there a way to achieve the same result on a left join?

**EDIT**

Result algorithm:

- Select the stuff from the original table car.
- take away anything not in table make if make has any content
- take away anything not in table model if model has any content....
- take away anything in table model2 if model2 has any content....

Thisnk of model2 a table of things I dont want, and model and make tables of things I do want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT colA, colB
FROM car
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM make) = 0) OR id IN (SELECT id FROM make))
  AND id IN (SELECT id from model)
```

With a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB
FROM car
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM make) mcount
LEFT JOIN make ON car.id = make.id
JOIN model ON car.id = model.id
WHERE mcount.c = 0 OR make.id IS NOT NULL
```

Using `OR` can often prevent use of indexes, so it may be better to use UNION:

```
SELECT distinct colA, colB
FROM car
JOIN make on car.id = make.id
JOIN model on car.id = model.id

UNION

SELECT distinct colA, colB
FROM car
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM make) make
JOIN model ON car.id = model.id
WHERE make.c = 0
```

Extending the `LEFT JOIN` version to both tables is straightforward:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colA, colB
FROM car
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM make) makecount
LEFT JOIN make ON car.id = make.id
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM model) modelcount
LEFT JOIN model ON car.id = model.id
WHERE (makecount.c = 0 OR make.id IS NOT NULL)
  AND (modelcount.c = 0 OR model.id IS NOT NULL)
```

If there are other tables to join with, you can just keep repeating this pattern.

Doing this with the UNION query is harder, because you would need a subquery for each combination of join tables that can be empty: one subquery for both `make` and `model` having rows, one for just `make`, one for just `model`, and one for both being empty. If there were 3 tables being joined with, this would expand to 8 subqueries (i.e. there will always be 2<sup>n</sup> subqueries). Maybe someone can come up with a way to do it better, I can't think of it off the top of my head.

Comment: Which would you say is the fastest, my tables are very very large.

Comment: MySQL is very bad at optimizing `WHERE IN (SELECT ...)`, so the JOIN is usually best.

Comment: `OR` also causes optimization problems in many cases, I added a `UNION` query that gets around this.

Comment: so this works when I test it with the example above. Can you show an example of n number of joins and checking to make sure they each have content.... So, the same concept as above but both join tables maybe empty in which case, there should be nothing limiting it.

Comment: I also added an edit of what the end result should look like. Sorry this is difficult to even explain.

Comment: Updated the answer to address multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do this with a more complicated join:

```
select c.colA, c.colB
from car c cross join
     (select count(*) as num from make) m
where num = 0 or
      (c.id in (select id from make) and 
       c.id in (select id from model)
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     select colA, colB from car
     left join make on make.id = car.id
     inner join model on model.id = car.is
     where make.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: INNER JOIN never returns null (unless the table actually contains NULL).